# What is the length of the ASP classic session.sessionid property?

Tags: asp-classic, sessionid

This is a simple question... yet I have spent some time poking around online to no avail.

In ASP classic (which I am unfortunately stuck with), I need to know the range of possible values returned by getting session.sessionid. I can print it just fine but without a better idea of how it works (besides the obvious incrementation), I don't trust testing to determine it.

Any information/resources/leads at all would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session IDs are created bij the server. Thus, `session.sessionid` gives you the ID generated by the server.

`session.sessionid` always gives you a **series of 9 digits**. As you can read in the sources below, the Session ID is always generated the same way (32 bit long integer, which gets encrypted).

Take a look at [this](http://seclists.org/pen-test/2008/Feb/119) resource. The [linked document](http://www.cgisecurity.com/lib/SessionIDs.pdf) in the article is an interesting read.

And [another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972338.aspx) article.